# Watir: How can I execute in a watir script a specific javascript function called on select of a checkbox?

Tags: watir, browser-automation, watir-webdriver

In a Watir script, after I check checkboxes in a popup window, I'm trying to execute a javascript function to add objects selected to the parent window.

What works fine until now it is the check of the checkbox, but object is not added to the parent window and I get following error when I executed the watir script:
in `method_missing': execScript (WIN32OLERuntimeError)

This was my approach - please let me know what other method I can use

```
ie.checkbox(:id => "check_asm0option0").set 
ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("window.triggerOriginalChange(asm0option0, add);","JavaScript") 

tr class="tr_option" rel="asm0option0"
td class="td_check"
input id="check_asm0option0" type="checkbox" value="4dbb118ddca3244e2800003d" rel="asm0option0" name="ignore"
/td
td class="td_li"
li value="0" rel="asm0option0" test /li
/td
/tr
```

Answer (score 0):

if using .set doesn't result in your code working the way you'd expect, then examine the source and then try using .fireEvent to fire the event that should trigger the script that needs to execute.

In this case I'd try

```
ie.checkbox(:id => "check_asm0option0").fireEvent('onChange')
```

that approach is generally a bit more organic and easier than trying to invoke the script manually